# Wrapping svg element with CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, resize

I want to make an svg element wrapper to dynamically resize it. I use `svg` inside the `div` of the element to which the wrapper `svg-wrapper` class is applied. My css looks like this:

```
.svg-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
}

svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  fill: red;
}
```

And html so:

```
<div class="svg-wrapper">
  <svg  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a2nj971t/

However, as you can see there is a problem that the `div` does not wrap the svg from below. Is it possible to fix it (Regardless of size of `svg`)?

Comment: you svg is a simple rect which make this issue trivial to fix ... you can probably share your real SVG?

Comment: `rect` fills all the svg, but I would like the `div` to completely wrap the `svg`, that is, to not see the gray fill.

Comment: I'm not clear exactly how you want it to work.  Is the problem the space at the bottom?  Because to have 100% padding on the bottom of the wrapper.

Comment: I understand what you want and since it's a simple rect, changing this with a simple background-color will *visually* fix the issue you want .. so probably you have a more complex SVG and a more complex situation

Comment: @JoeFitzsimmons the SVG is position:absolute so padding won't bother it